# Why is my python input function not working in tynker?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I desperatly need this tynker project for a robotics project and I've ran into a bit of a pickle. I've got the following code here, but the `input()` function isn't showing the space to answer and just skips it, even though it's showing the prompt. Here's a minimal reproducible example below. Please help!

```
import turtle
screen = turtle.Screen()
a = input("test")
import turtle, random, math
screen = turtle.Screen()
screen.bgcolor("green")
screen.delay(0)

sprite = turtle.Turtle()
sprite.penup()
sprite.speed(0)
sprite.ht()
player = sprite.clone()
player.shape("turtle")
player.color("#35d03a")
player.seth(90)
player.goto(0,-180)
player.st()
cars = []
car_speed = []
print("Choose a difficulty from 1-16")
d = sprite.textinput(title, prompt, default=None, minval=None, maxval=None)
#d = 16
print("You chose difficulty " + str(d) + ".")
for i in range(10):
    car = sprite.clone()
    car.shape('square')
    if i % 2:
        car.seth(0)
    else:
        car.seth(180)

    car.goto(random.randint(-200,200),-120+i*(300/10))
    car.st()
    cars.append(car)
    gauss = random.gauss(10.0 + int(d), 20.0)
    car_speed.append(gauss)
#update function and non-setup things
```

I've spent hours trying to debug it, but I can't find the error and if I try to not hard-code it, I get a `ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '' on line 33`. It started with the `gauss = random.gauss(10.0 + int(d), 20.0)` on line 33 when the input thing didn't pop up, and I realized that the input was recieving "", so something was wrong. Now when I hard-code it, it works but I want the input. I've been trying to reasearch this. Please help!

Error message with no hard code:

```
Choose a difficulty from 1-16
You chose difficulty .
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '' on line 33
```

Edit: When I run this, I get the same screen—white screen with no prompt OR answer method. Not even anything in the console.

Comment: What do you mean by " but the input() function isn't showing the space to answer"?

Comment: I mean that it just skips the line of code and runs it like a print() function. For example, input("ABC") would be run as print("ABC"). It shows the prompt but doesn't give me the capability to answer.

Comment: What environment are you running your code in? Try the command line.

Comment: I'm running it in tynker.

Comment: I've never used tynker myself, but FWIW, your next step should probably be to make a [mre]. Like maybe this would suffice: `x = int(input()); print(x)`. If you always get an error no matter what you try, then maybe stdin is hooked up to an infinite stream of newlines, like `yes ''` (Unix shell command), and maybe you're supposed to use something other than `input()`.

Comment: There is no way we can possibly explain what is wrong at line 33 of the program, if we are only shown the first three lines. Please read [mre].

Comment: This isn't a duplicate. It doesn't let me put an answer in.

Comment: Also, textinput() and numinput() don't work.